# Question on word-usage: synergetic, synergistic, or synergy

Tags: word-usage

In environmental psychology there is a specific cumulative effect which has been referred to in literature as:

- synergetic effect

> E.g.: Potential **synergetic** effects between local road traffic noise and wind turbine noise cannot be excluded based on the current experiment.  [from: T. Van Renterghem et al. / Science of the Total Environment 456 -457 (2013) 333-345]
>   
>   and

- synergistic effect

> E.g.: The future studies should focus on potential **synergistic** effect of road traffic noise and
>   air pollution on hypertension and myocardial infarction. [from: WHO, Burden of disease from environmental noise: Practical guidance, 2010] 
>   
>   Between these two usages, there is no difference in the meaning. In French we would say "l'effet de synergie" directly translated: "the synergy effect".

Now, I just would like to express that this effect is present in my current data set:

> The synergetic/synergistic/synergy effect has been observed in the current data set.

Which usage do you think is correct from a grammatical point of view?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You'd say "*the synergistic effect*" or just "*the synergy*" (without *effect*). I prefer the former.

Comment: I like synergy without effect, or synergistic effect*s*.

Comment: I've never encountered "synergetic".  I think it's a mistaken conflation of "synergistic" and "synergetics", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergetics_(Fuller), or perhaps just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

An Ngram chart for "the synergetic effects" (blue line) versus "the synergistic effects" (red line) versus "the synergy effects" (green line) for the period 1940–2005 shows a very substantial preference in the publications included in the Google Books database for the second option, with the first and third options roughly equal to each other in popularity:

[image]

A seond Ngram chart for the singular version of each phrase—"the synergetic effect" (blue line) versus "the synergistic effect" (red line) versus "the synergy effect" (green line)—over the same period yields fairly similar results, albeit on a somewhat larger scale:

[image]

The upshot is that most writers referring in compact form to the effects (or effect) of synergy prefer the wording "the synergistic effect(s)," and those who don't are about evenly divided between "the synergetic effect(s) and "the synergy effect(s)."

Answer (score 0):

I've always felt the term *synergistic* felt silly, though I concede I hear it much more often than synergetic.  The concept of synergy as I understood it was a combination of components or factors that is greater than the sum of the parts.  The word is clearly derived from "syn" meaning together and energy which is work or heat (technically force times distance).  We would never say energistic but often use energetic.  Therefore it seems that since we tend to abide by grammatical forms of the root when adding a prefix, we should do the same in this case. Energy -> Energetic and not Energistic; Synergy -> Synergetic and not Synergistic

Answer (score -1):

*Synergetic* is [much rarer than](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synergetic%2Csynergistic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynergetic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csynergistic%3B%2Cc0) *synergistic*.

Shouldn't the singular "effect" be "effects"?

P.S. In my experience, *synergy* tends to be used with positive connotations in business writing: the final effect is *enhanced* by the combination of factors. Perhaps *synergetic* is an attempt to describe the combination of factors in a *neutral* way?

Comment: Thank you! If you talk about this effect in general the use of plural is absolutely fine I think ("Synergetic effects are present"). However, I have one figure in which a combination of two noises exhibits this specific effect. Taking into account your comment, I'd say "The synergistic effect is present". Are you ok with this?

Comment: I would write: *A synergetic effect has been observed in the data.* first because *synergistic* has positive connotations in normal everyday use (and your examples show noise having a negative effect on health) and second, the indefinite article "A" because "The" suggests that the effect is the same wherever it occurs.  Caveat: I write a lot, and have taught writing in a university, but I don't write scientific prose.